# Get sensor data using Crazyflie ROS Package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I'm new to ROS, I just learnt the basic but I have never coded ROS before. However, I need to get/store sensor data from Crazyflie and publish it on the screen for my project. Can anyone give me some steps I need to do or some references with similar code I can consult to achieve my purpose? If it's possible, the simple or detailed it is, the better.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258873/get-sensor-data-using-crazyflie-ros-package/) by [thanhvu94](https://answers.ros.org/users/29865/thanhvu94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2017-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Welcome to the ROS Community! Searching around the ROS wiki will give you the answer most of the times!

I found [this package](http://wiki.ros.org/crazyflie) while looking for relevant stuff. Assuming you have Crazyflie 1.0 (or 2.0 with stock firmware) this package promises to work out of the box for you! Unfortunately I do not have a Crazyflie to test it, but seems like a good start even if it is not exactly what you need.

For a quick example, if you just need all the imu data that is being published to be stored in a file, you could just open a terminal (while the driver of the Crazyflie is running), and execute `rostopic echo /topic_name >> filename.txt` while replacing topic_name with your preferred topic (/imu) and filename.txt with your preferred file.

Good luck with your project!

---

Originally posted by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) with karma: 641 on 2017-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0